# Accesing only immediate preceding sibling in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am using XSLT 1.0. Currently am in `<w:t>` template. I want to check if the preceding sibling `w:r(id=3)` has `<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>`.

I'm want the immediate preceding sibling only and not `w:r` having `id=2` or `id=1`.

```
<t xmlns:w="http://example.com">
    <w:r id="1">
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="start"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r id="2">
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="tocStartRef_1"/>
    <w:r id="3">
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    <w:r id="4">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="Span"/>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="arial" w:eastAsia="arial" 
                      w:hAnsi="arial" w:cs="arial"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:sz w:val="32"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Fonts</w:t>
    </w:r>
</t>
```

Comment: please post well-formed and properly indented XML. I will downvote next time.

Comment: Do note that `w:t` element has no preceding sibling `w:r` but just preceding ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the xpath `preceding-sibling` axis like this:

```
preceding-sibling::w:r[1]/w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType = 'end'
```

which will select the nearest (`[1]`) `preceding-sibling` named `w:r`, then descend to any child element(s) named `w:fldChar`, then any attributes from there named `w:fldCharType`, then if any such node exists whose text is `'end'`, returns true.

Comment: Also, it's always worth mentioning that the `ancestor`, `ancestor-or-self`, `preceding`, and `preceding-sibling` axes are reverse axes, so position predicates can look surprising.